# Finding all partitions with filesystems

Tags: filesystems, partition, block-device

I'm writing a script that will copy all of the files on a device to a directory. The problem is that some of the devices have multiple partitions and some of the partitions don't have filesystems to copy files from. At the moment, I'm thinking about using `lsblk` to get a list of partitions on the device and `file -s` to check for a filesystem on each partition.

Is there a less brute way to do what I am trying to do?

---

Here is information regarding the empty partition problem:

```
# /dev/sdb is a flashdrive with two partitions
# /dev/sdb1 has no filesystem
# /dev/sdb2 has an ext4 partition
$ lsblk -fi
...
sdb    vfat   CARRIER-R C84B-6A72                            
|-sdb1 vfat   CARRIER-R C84B-6A72                            
`-sdb2 ext4   CARRIER-R 33ebb632-68a5-4bf5-bd29-90733af9699e
...

$ lsblk -ln -o NAME,FSTYPE
...
sdb  vfat
sdb1 vfat
sdb2 ext4
...

# As confirmation, mounting the partition fails
$ mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1
...

$ dmesg | tail
...
[  985.933627] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  985.935722] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  985.937603] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  985.939623] FAT-fs (sdb1): invalid media value (0xa7)
[  985.939627] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

Comment: `udisks` is probably your best bet, if you have it running.

Comment: See the `-f` option of lsblk.

Comment: @don_crissti: Thanks. I was trying `lsblk -fnr | grep '^sda.\ ' | awk '{ print "$1 $2" }'` before. I should have spent more time in the man page.

Comment: I seem to be having one problem. `lsblk` seems to think that partitions without filesystems on them have vfat filesystems.

Comment: I'll try a different flashdrive. Just in case it's relevent, I am using Arch Linux with the stock kernel. The tools were installed from their respective pacman packages.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem a bit. The flashdrive had a GPT partition table. If I make an MBR partition table on it, `lsblk` doesn't show filesystem information for partitions without filesystems.

Comment: I zeroed out all of the partitions on the drive and `lsblk` no longer detects filesystems on them. There must have been some lingering filesystem data lying around. I should have realized that earlier. I am curious as to why `lsblk` detected filesystems on the filesystem-less partitions while `blkid` did not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think `lsblk` and `file -s` is that ugly, but there is an alternate way.
You can use `blkid` instead. By default, `blkid` without any arguments will list the known block devices, and a little bit of information about them, including the filesystem type. The format is also in key=value pair format (by default), which makes it easy to dump into a script.

This is what the output looks like on my system:

```
>> blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="boot" UUID="5F6E-FD2B" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="yBVbC2-MFnP-1T1s-9XGz-VCUH-S5oG-aNSXDg" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/sys-root: UUID="0e1e5a6b-31b2-4e13-9b26-cbbb74e95ab9" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/mapper/sys-var--log: UUID="49f1b45d-d303-4c2e-a72b-c75e8f1e27ae" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/mapper/sys-usr--portage: UUID="b8a494dd-f7f4-4e5e-9975-e21a61c95d22" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/mapper/sys-stmp: UUID="f2b3252c-3ec2-4c66-bed2-26c93f12b535" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/mapper/sys-home--phemmer--luks: UUID="898f9f52-3c9d-475c-9e7b-1a2263778a39" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
/dev/mapper/_dev_dm_4: UUID="d0cb5255-e35a-4ee2-94ca-f1a7f7339eb9" TYPE="xfs"
```

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and use `blkid`: `blkid -o full | grep 'TYPE=' | grep -o '^/dev/sdb.'`

Comment: The problem that I have faced so far with `blkid` is that it does not print all the devices until I have run it with `sudo` at least once. That is to say, on the later invokes of `blkid` it prints out all the devices fine, only the first time it needs `sudo`.
On the other hand, since I don't care about dirty if I can get what I want, I think `udisksctl` (or in other systems `udisks` is really a good tool since it gives out all the info without being `sudo` invoked and I can use `grep` and `awk` to get my fields easily. I like to keep `sudo` out of my scripts as much as possible.